# Docker Compose Error: Additional property ports is not allowed

Tags: docker

Я создал файл Docker Compose и при попытке создать контейнер, мне выдает следующую ошибку:
(root) Additional property ports is not allowed

Как выглядит сам файл:

```
    version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123
    - POSTGRES_DB=game_platform_db
ports:
  - '5423:5432'
```

Я пытался запустить выполнение от имени Администратора не помогло.

Answer (score 2):

У вас отступы не правильные, `ports` должно относиться к `postgres`, т.е. так:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123
      - POSTGRES_DB=game_platform_db
    ports:
      - '5423:5432'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!